# Не работaет запрос AJAX и JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json

### Проблема с AJAX

Когда я убираю `dataType: 'json'`, то `success:` работает, а иначе нет. Так как 
`$("#log-form").serialize()` тоже работает, но в самом файле `login.php` ничего не происходит.

---

Как мне возвратить `json-строку`. Я планировал сделать так: если значение этой `json-строки` равно `"false-pass"`, то сделать определенный кусок `js-кода`

---

**В общем, две проблемы:
как сделать `json-запрос`? (я слышал что-то о `$.getJson`);
и почему не отправляются данные в файл `login.php`?**

---

```
         $('#log-form').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'login.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: $("#log-form").serialize(),
                    success: function(){
                        console.log($("#log-form").serialize());
                    }
                })
                .done(function() {
                    console.log("success");
                });
            });
```

***`login.php:`***

```
<? 
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['logged-in']) {
    echo 'Доступ заборонено!';
    exit;
}
else {

    require_once 'database.php'; 
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);


    if (isset($_POST['log-submit-n']) && !$_SESSION['logged-in']) {
        $login = $_POST['log-login-n'];
        $pass = $_POST['log-pass-n'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login'";
        $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
        $id = $row['id'];

        if ($row_count == 1) {
            $db_pass = $row['password'];
            $db_login = $row['login'];

            if ($login == $db_login && $pass == $db_pass) {
                $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
                $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            } 
            else if ($login == $db_login && $pass!=$db_pass) {
                $error = "false-pass";
                json_encode($error);
            }
        }
        else {
            $error = "none-acc";
            json_encode($error);
        }
    } 
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

Comment: @rjhdby, не подскажите, что эта строка означает?) И..только что вписал её в `login.php`, но я так понял, что данные сёравно не отправляются в этот файл

Comment: а вы сами, руками в браузере, не пробовали делать этот запрос? Отдает корректный json?

Comment: Эта строка принудительно указывает, что возвращается тип данных json

Comment: @rjhdby, да пробовал вручную писать, ничего не происходит.

Comment: Ну если вам сервер ничего не отдает, то что вы намереваетесь получать в success? А когда вы убираете `dataType: 'json'`, то клиентская часть получает ответ с кодом 200 и пустым содержимым - вполне себе success. Разбирайтесь с кодом PHP, почему он ничего ене возвращает

Comment: А я даже знаю, почему ничего не возвращается. Вы забыли везде перед `json_encode($.....);` поставить `echo`

Comment: @rjhdby, хмм. Поставил, особо ничего не изменилось) Теперь я думаю, что проблема в самом ajax-запросе. А как мне вернуть строку json в js?

Comment: Если вы руками, в браузере, обратились к своему PHP скрипту и он вам ничего не вернул, то каким боком тут вообще ajax запрос?

Comment: @rjhdby, я наверное вас неправильно понял был:) В общем, я даже не знаю, что здесь может быть не так. И не знаю как проверить. что работает, а что нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как Вы посылаете содержимое формы вручную (ajax-ом), то `value` кнопки с `name="log-submit-n"` в посылаемые данные не включается. Ваш серверный скрипт обернут в условие, проверяющее наличие в запросе `$_POST['log-submit-n']`. Этого ключа в запросе нет - ответ пустой, потому что Вы ничего в ответ не пишите.

*Спрашивающему на заметку:*

Удачно, что у меня сегодня хорошо работают телепатические способности. В такие вопросы следует включать html.

*Update*

В случае неудачной авторизации:

```
echo json_encode(array('result' => 'error', 'message' => 'explain what was wrong', data => NULL));
```

В случае удачной авторизации:

```
echo json_encode(array('result' => 'success', 'message' => 'All is good.', data => your_data));
```

В js:

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data.result != "success") {
    // show error information to the user
    alert(data.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне избежать этого условия..? Даже не так. Как мне сделать так, что бы это было безопасно?)

Comment: @Cactus Хм, убрать `if` из кода.

Comment: аха)) Ну окей, с этим очень вам благодарен. А как на счет возврата json-строки. Как в `success:` сделать условие на неверность пароля, т.е. что с этим делать `echo json_encode($error);`?

Comment: @Cactus Добавил.

Comment: да , вижу. А если мне нужно просто переменную или строку вернуть?

Comment: @Cactus Добавил.

Comment: Благодарю. Теперь все ясно:)